# how to add white space in html text field after every 4 numbers

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to figure out how to add white space within the textfield while editing. I have a 16 digit number and i want a white space after every 4th number

My digit it like 1010101010101010

and i want like 1010 1010 1010 1010 (with in textfield)

Answer (score 0):

You can get every character of your digit and in loop add space to text.

```js
var text = "1010101010101010";
var charac = text.split("");

var newText = "";
charac.forEach(function(value, index){
    if (index % 4 == 0)
        newText += " ";
        
    newText += value;
});

document.write(newText);
```